# Android how to draw a shape defined in xml on canvas

Tags: android, drawable, android-canvas

I defined a dotted line in the xml:

```
<shape android:shape="line" >
    <stroke
        android:dashGap="2dp"
        android:dashWidth="2dp"
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#C69EA2" />
</shape>
```

I load it as a drawable and try to draw it under each line of EditText:

```
Rect r = mRect;
int baseline = getLineBounds( line , r);
drawable.setBounds(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 2);
divider.draw(canvas);
```

However, it only show a solid line, not a dotted one.
what is the problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally, I found that it is effected by hard acceleration.
so just close it and everything will be fine.

Comment: example:

yourView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);